# Make dynamic SVG scrollable

Tags: javascript, svg, react-native

In my react native app, there is a view, which shows a progress graph. This graph is constructed dynamically with the help of SVG ( react-native-svg npm ) and its features like Line, Circle and Rect.

For few of the input data the graph goes big and out of the screen and need to add scroll so that user can scroll and see the full graph.

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.data,'subject analysis');
    const {width,height} = getDeviceSize();
    let svgWidth = width;
    let svgHeight = height;
    .... creation logic goes here .....
}

return (
      <View>
        <Svg
          height={height * 0.854}
          width={width}
        >
</Svg>
</View>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html), however it will be restricted in one direction. If you need to scroll/pan in both directions, you can do that using [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html)